# Is there a way for me to implicitly bind the members of a let/match operation?

Tags: rust

E.g. in the code below, ThreeD is an enum which can either be a Point or a Vector. The function ***cross*** is intended to calculate the cross product of two Vectors, and panic if either argument is a Point.

In order to calculate the result I need the x, y and z components of both the lhs and the rhs. As it stands however the second match will obscure the x,y and z members from the first match.

One option is to explicitly assign the x, y, and z members to temporary variables, immediately after the first let statement, but this feels horribly klunky.

```
pub fn cross(lhs: ThreeD, rhs: ThreeD) -> ThreeD {
    if let Vector { x, y, z } = lhs {
        let lhs_x = x;    // I DON'T LIKE THIS APPROACH!
        let lhs_y = y;    //
        let lhs_z = z;    //

        if let Vector { x, y, z } = rhs {
            // dummy calc here - I know this is wrong ;-)
            Vector { x: lhs_x * x, y: lhs_y * y, z: lhs_z * z }
        } else {
            panic!("Cannot calculate cross product with a point")
        }
    } else {
        panic!("Cannot calculate cross product against a point")
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit confusing for me, if we are expecting the types to be `Vector` why allow the function to accept `ThreeD` and then panic?

Comment: @MuhammadFarag I think you may be right. At the time it seemed like a good idea to make Vector and Point both members of an enum, but now I'm not so sure. Fortunately, it should be easy enough refactor into two separate structs if this makes more sense.

Comment: I understand why you might decide to make it as an enum. The ergonomics of working with enums is a bit weird in `Rust`.  You cannot implement methods on enum members.

What I have seen as an alternative is creating a struct with the same name as the enum member. `struct Vector {}`, `struct Point {}`. Then `
enum ThreeD { Vector(Vector), Point(Point),}`
impl Vector {
    fn product(&self, other: &Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector { x: self.x * other.x, }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to a different name within the pattern using this syntax:

```
if let Vector { x: lhs_x, y: lhs_y, z: lhs_z } = lhs {
```

Comment: Perfect! What a lovely language - brevity and elegance ;-)